# Minio + Upload Metadata + Object?

Tags: object, hadoop, upload, metadata, minio

anybody know, maybe Minio not result and best product for it, but i need upload many objects and metadata and then i need can find this objects over metadata and get uri? I had install Monio server on Ubuntu 18.04 and i can't unserstand how i can do this func?

I need many files upload with metadata like position num, size, weight and other metadata of object;
I need good performance like 1000 objects per hour;
Upload with REST in URI data or the same.

Maybe some system already have this functions, like Hadoop or Minio or other?

Anybody know solved? Thank you so much.

Comment: As i know, Minio have MINIO SDK where i seen: opts minio.PutObjectOptions Allows user to set optional custom metadata, content headers, encryption keys and number of threads for multipart upload operation.

But how example upload object to Minio with metadata?

Comment: Maybe have some better product with opensorce or box product for this task? Any way, any example? Maybe this will can solved with python or some SDK API Minio?

Comment: Any example, how upload object with metadata? Please.

Comment: I found this, how this simple use, i am not a programmist... 8-( thx
https://github.com/minio/minio-js/blob/master/examples/fput-object.js

https://github.com/minio/minio-py/blob/3d01781eb0fc14857e1e11014483cdfd0186cb36/tests/functional/tests.py#L316-L334

https://github.com/minio/minio/blob/9aeedc4c5f327e6299382d6238f8fcee03e23b9b/cmd/object-api-datatypes.go#L149-L153

Comment: Is there any example of implementation to put an object with metadata and get an object using metadata? THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

@AlexPebody You can use the minio client `mc` or any minio sdk to upload an object with metadata.
You can run the below command which uploads object with metadata

```
Copy a list of objects from local file system to MinIO cloud storage with specified metadata, separated by ";"
      $ mc cp --attr "key1=value1;key2=value2" Music/*.mp4 play/mybucket/
```

As far as searching against metadata is concerned S3 does not have an API for searching metadata or tags of objects in a bucket. To achieve this, you could turn on event notifications to a configured web hook endpoint, which can then be used to search for objects with certain metadata/tags

The head object returns all the metadata associated with the object
You can also use the object tagging feature and get the tags of objects using  Get Object Tags.